# Rails Testing Error - NameError: TestCase::SUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, minitest, ruby-2.1

In my Rails app, I've updated Ruby from `1.9.3` to `2.1.0`. Now when I restart my tests I get an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MiniTest::Unit::TestCase::SUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL
```

Here are gems in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'json'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rak'
gem 'rails-translate-routes'
gem 'routes'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 3.2.3"
  gem 'uglifier', ' >= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
`NameError: uninitialized constant MiniTest::Unit::TestCase::SUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/mocha-0.10.5/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test/version_230_to_262.rb:19:in `run'`
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:36:in `block in run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__4401979439353622961__setup__4295356768171603498__callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@kalender/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:940:in `block in _run_suite'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `map'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `_run_suite'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:663:in `block in _run_suites'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:661:in `each'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:661:in `_run_suites'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `_run_anything'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1092:in `run_tests'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1079:in `block in _run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1078:in `each'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1078:in `_run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1066:in `run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:780:in `run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:372:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:33:in `run_once'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:371:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: It works with ruby 1.9.3 and ruby-2.0.0-p481

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just came across a bug that is similar or identical to this one and was able to resolve it locally. For me, I had a trace that begins with:

```
/home/youruser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mocha-0.10.5/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test/version_230_to_262.rb:19:in `run': uninitialized constant MiniTest::Unit::TestCase::SUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL (NameError)
```

This shows that the error is actually occurring in mocha when it tries to reference a constant that has been removed from the version of minitest that likely came along with your Ruby upgrade.

For me, doing a `bundle update mocha` fixed the problem.

Doing a bit of code spelunking to figure out specifically where the problem was fixed, I used the "git pickaxe" (`git log -SSUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL`) on a cloned copy of the mocha repository, and it seems like [this commit removed the reference to SUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/commit/024fdb8897a3832), so using anything after that commit in mocha should be ok.

If upgrading your version of mocha doesn't solve the problem, take a close look at the stack trace and you should see which library that depends minitest having SUPPORTS_INFO_SIGNAL defined is causing the error. Then look upstream in that dependency to see if this problem was fixed. If not, fork the dependency you're using that exhibits this behavior and push your own patch upstream.

Comment: unfortunately its not working for me,
i installed mini-test and mocha with newest version

Comment: @pukoo can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: After reporting an Issue on Github/minitest, zenspider recommended to use the newest mocha gem, because its an 'mocha' bug.  **In my case, i haven't use 'mocha' directly in my Gemfile.**  But another Gem 'capybara' had dependencies to mocha.  **I declared the 'mocha' Gem in my Gemfile too, and it works.**